# Ember.js {{action}} other than click

Tags: ember.js

Lets say I have a template with several `button` elements in it. If I want to watch for a `click` event then I just use the `{{action}}` helper. But I can't figure out a way of passing other events like `mouseEnter` or `mouseLeave`. I would have thought to use `Ember.Button` and somehow do it through `childViews` but it seems to be [deprecated](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/commit/4b2f5e7b8145914cdf451361355acf0fccae49a8).

template

```
{{#view App.MyView}}
    <button {{action "btnClicked"}}>button1</button>
    <button {{action "btnClicked"}}>button2</button>
{{/view}}
```

js

```
App.MyView = Em.View.extend({
    btnClicked: function(e){
       alert('btnClicked');
    },
    btnMouseEnter: function(e){
       alert('btnMouseEnter'); // how to call this?
    }
});​
```

I know I can use `{{action "btnMouseEnter" on="mouseEnter"}}` but then I lose the click functionality.
Do I need to wrap each button in its own `Ember.View`? If so, why was `Ember.Button` deprecated?

**Edit:**

I think you should be be able to have multiple events trigger the same `action`

```
<button {{action "myAction" on="click mouseEnter mouseLeave"}}>button</button>
```

I implemented this behavior in my [fork](https://github.com/icholy/ember.js/commit/59efa5110bda1a764cb97d0f32574e735290944e) and [here](http://jsfiddle.net/U3thg/28/) is a jsFiddle demonstrating it working

**Edit:**

if someone is also interested in this functionality, the discussion is going on [here](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/994).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Very good question IMHO.

The only way I found is this one: http://jsfiddle.net/Sly7/Zvred/

I think it's a kind of wrapping, so not sure it's a good answer...

Answer (score 6):

Ilia...

The Ember team decided that allowing multiple action helpers on an element like Button wasn't a best practice. Their recommendation is to use a view like sly7_7 suggests. Please review this issue report on Github:

https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/569

Comment: +1 for the link. What a pity they didn't explain why they choose to not implement multiple actions support.

Comment: I think you will have answers in the issue you hav posted ;)

Comment: A tipical case for having two action helpers on the same element is a upload in a newer ui: you need to make it work on click and on drop. Sure, it is possible to do it anyways, but I think I would like to have such a opportunity.